# How to sum row by row using app scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to sum row by row and have values in grand total cell for respective rows.
I tried looping in the app scripts. But couldn't. Can anyone help me with this?

I have this data from b3:f16 and I need grand total in h3:h16

```
1906    904     106 221 1640
1771    842      97 188 1338
3221    1005    252 260 6323
3239    1141    317 287 7828
3556    1409    352 337 8890
3417    1307    303 382 7143
3264    1824    358 444 9288
2724    1916    196 395 3462
2641    1829    151 430 3255
4076    1858    398 471 12844
3986    2098    468 426 13411
4829    2504    422 514 14449
4462    4876    452 507 13285
5017    6654    423 410 7765
```

Code:

```
function adder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange("B3:F16").getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange("H3:H16");

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length ; j++) {
      sum += data[i][j];
    }
   range.setValue(sum);
   Logger.log(sum);
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

this could be done with MMULT..

In G3, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(B3:F16, transpose(column(B3:F3)^0)))
```

If you want to use script, see if this works:

```
function adder() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName("sheet1"),
    res = [];
    sheet.getRange("B3:F16")
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r) {
            res.push([r.reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a + b;
            })])
        });
sheet.getRange("H3:H16")
    .setValues(res);
}
```

or with 'classic' for loops:

```
function adder2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName("Test"),
    res = [],
    sum,
    data = sheet.getRange("B3:F16")
        .getValues();
for (var i = 0, rlen = data.length; i < rlen; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0, clen = data[0].length; j < clen; j++) {
        sum += Number(data[i][j])
    }
    res.push([sum])
}
sheet.getRange("H3:H16")
    .setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Krishna: Most welcome. If this worked for you please accept the answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or upvote.